# Basic Auth in Docker Registry

Tags: docker

I am trying to setup a basic authentication in docker registry, followed the steps mentioned in docker docs.

After the below docker run command

```
docker run \
  --entrypoint htpasswd \
  registry:2 -Bbn testuser testpassword > auth/htpasswd
```

I am getting an error as:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec:
> "htpasswd": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Has anyone else encountered this issue & what was the fix forward ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`htpasswd` binary is no longer provided in registry docker image, you can generate the htpasswd on any machine where `htpasswd` is available (provided by `httpd-tools` rpm on CentOS/Redhat)

```
htpasswd -Bbn testuser testpassword > auth/htpasswd
```

Comment: Thank you. The docker docs seems to be missing this info.